# Ajax request again after successful return of last request

Tags: php, ajax

Hello all I would like to send a request after my first request succeeds

The following is what I am using to make the initial request

```
$('#registerUser').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({             
  type: 'get',
  url: 'GM/checkUserExists',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  success: function () {



  }
      });

      return false;
  });
```

In order to make the second requewst I am using the following that is not working, it is loading the page but it is loading the page which I don't want. I am sure I am doing this wrong but any help getting me past this would be great.

```
$('#registerUser').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({             
  type: 'get',
  url: 'GM/checkUserExists',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  success: function () {

    type: 'get',
    url: 'GM/checkUserExists',
    data: $('form').serialize(),

  }
      });

      return false;
  });
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a function ???  --- http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/  -- seperate the 2nd ajax call you have into its own function and call it in the -- success: function () -- of the first one. To call a function all you need to do is eg --- myfunction(); .

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think it's back to the books for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why do you get twice `checkUserExists` ?

```
$('#registerUser').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'GM/checkUserExists',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

            // IF YOU WANT TO CALL A SECOND AJAX REQUEST

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'GM/checkUserExists',
                data: $('form').serialize()
                // success: function ....
            });
        }
    });

    // return false; // DONT NEED IT IF YOU HAVE e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry dude no was just an example I need to register the user but have to make separate API calls